# Truncate string in r from an inconsistently placed, duplicated character

Tags: r, substring

I'm dealing with address data that is in strings, and I want to extract just the postcode. These are consistently at the end of the string, but can be different lengths (for e.g., "XXX XXX" or "XX XXX" or "XXXX XXX"). 
They also consistently have "\n" before them - but this happens several other times in the string. I think the ideal solution would be to extract all data that comes after the final "\n", but I don't know how to do this! I can find ways to truncate data after a specific character, but not if that character appears several times.

**Example of a string:**

```
"22 Generic Road,\nNotville,\nFaketon,\nUnited Kingdom,\nAB1 2CD"
```

EDIT TO ADD:
My workaround for this is to approach it in two steps: first, truncate the string to the final 11 characters (to ensure getting the total postcode and \n for all columns); second, extract all characters following \n. But presumably this is unnecessarily cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you expect, In this case there are many ways to solve this, `gsub` is one of the way, you can use `str_extract` from `stringr` as well or `gregexpr` from Base R :

```
gsub("(.*)\n(\\w+\\s+\\w+)$","\\2", x)
```

**Logic**:

Selecting the last alphanumeric word using \w , since there is more than one hence using the greedy character of + (one or more matches), since it is present at the ending of sentence use the "$" to make it work, The pattern of matching is one word separated with space with another , hence there are two \w+ and one \s+ for space. Wrapping these matches in a capturing group (using parenthesis, these are used for capturing the match )and replacing the entire match with this capturing group gives us the result.

---

**Using** `stringr::str_extract`

```
stringr::str_extract(x, "(\\w+\\s+\\w+)$")
```

**Output**:

```
> gsub("(.*)\n(\\w+\\s+\\w+)$","\\2", x)
[1] "AB1 2CD"
```

**Input data:**

```
x <- "22 Generic Road,\nNotville,\nFaketon,\nUnited Kingdom,\nAB1 2CD"
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to work! I'll mark the answer as correct. How is it doing it?